# Sort by decreasing order based on individual column variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr, group-by

I'm hoping to sort a dataframe by it's individual groups based on it's individual column value. A sample dataframe is as follows:

| Group | Answer | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Apple | 12 |
| B | Apple | 8 |
| A | Orange | 11 |
| B | Orange | 3 |
| A | Banana | 20 |
| B | Banana | 5 |
| A | Jackfruit | 10 |
| B | Jackfruit | 9 |
| A | Pineapple | 5 |
| B | Pineapple | 3 |
| A | Pear | 20 |
| B | Pear | 20 |

```
df_sample = structure(list(Group = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                               2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), 
                           Answer = structure(c(1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
                                                6L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Apple", "Banana", "Jackfruit", "Orange", 
                                                                        "Pear", "Pineapple"), class = "factor"), Frequency = c(12L, 
                           8L, 11L, 3L, 20L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 5L, 3L, 20L, 20L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                           -12L))
```

I'm hoping to sort them based on the Group column and to output the top 3 answers based on the frequency for each group. The outcome should be the following table.

| Group | Answer (top 3) | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Pear | 20 |
| A | Banana | 20 |
| A | Apple | 12 |
| B | Pear | 20 |
| B | Jackfruit | 9 |
| B | Apple | 8 |

If I'm not wrong the code should be something alone the line of but I'm not sure how to complete it

```
df_sample %>% group_by(Group) %>% order(Frequency, decreasing = T)
```

Thanks!

Comment: In `dplyr`, use the `arrange` function to order rows. You can do `df_sample %>% arrange(Group, desc(Frequency))` or `df_sample %>% group_by(Group) %>% arrange(desc(Frequency), .by_group = TRUE)`.

Comment: To get top 3, use the `slice_max` utility function: `df_sample %>% group_by(Group) %>% slice_max(Frequency, n = 3)`